# jQuery - Selector for data returned from .post

Tags: jquery

I am doing a simple jQuery post:

```
$.post('/form.html', 
            $("#form").serialize(),
            function(data, textStatus) {
//Selector for finding a field in the data
});
```

How do I process a selector against the variable data?

I need to look for a specific id that exists within the html
returned from the post call?

Comment: Would .indexOf(id) not be sufficient in this case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is the data a block of HTML that has an HTML element with an id?

For example, say the data returned from the post looks like

```
"<div><p id='firstParagraph'>Some text</p><input type='hidden' id='hiddenField' value="42">Some more text</p></div>"
```

and say that you just want to pull out the value of the  "hiddenField" element.  You can do

```
$.post('/form.html', 
            $("#form").serialize(),
            function(data, textStatus) {
                  var hiddenValue = $("#hiddenField", $(data) ).val();
                  //hiddenValue now equals "42"
});
```

The `$(data)` part in the selector is creating a context in which the selector will operate.  `$("#hiddenField", $(data) ).val()` is the exact equivalent of doing `$(data).find("#hiddenField").val()`.

Comment: This is exactly what I am trying to do.  I have html like your example being returned into the data field and I want to select the value of a hidden input field to determine what to do next.

Comment: Modified my example to fit your description more precisely.

Answer (score 1):

```
$(data).find(your_selector_here)
```