# Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Getting the above error when I am running a jquery function.

I get the whole html document passed back to me so finding what exactly is wrong is a bit hard and I am not 100% sure what might be causing it. I am basically changing html content within a location when a button is clicked.

(Loading more articles and removing the rest)

```
function attachMoreArticlesAction() {     
    $('.more-posts div a').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropagation();

        var url = $(this).attr('href');
        $.get(url, function(html){
            var body = $(html).find('.member').html();

            $('.member').append(body);
            attachMoreArticlesAction();
        });

        return false;
    });
}
```

Thats the function I am currently using. Could anyone tell me why I am getting this error.

Thanks heaps.

Comment: What line is the exception being thrown on?  Could you post the return value of your $.get

Comment: The browser tools should give you the line number of the error, and you should be able to click to be taken right to the problem.

Comment: Guessing it's coming from `$(html)`, where your `html` is somehow being interpreted as an invalid selector string. You should really be responding with only the desired content instead of an entire page.

Comment: Here's a demo of what I mean: http://jsfiddle.net/FYueX/1/

Comment: its in foundation.js

Thats where the error is been thrown from. Doubt anything will be wrong with that so I am not sure why this is happening...

Comment: $(html) is not part of the dom at this point. You should only be passing back the necessary content as user2736012 said. Alternatively, you may be able to assign a temporary element the contents of html, then attempt to run the selector on the temporary element

Comment: See the answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6218759/jquery-selector-for-data-returned-from-post

Comment: Thing is this code works on a different page but not the current one Im trying on. And i cannot assign specific html to search from and I also cant get only a section of html. and I need to use this method on various parts of the whole document. (I am going to make the search class specific to each section I want but for testing purposes have assigned one.)

Comment: Right but the answer in that link shows how to run the selector on the returned object. Slightly different than your method. worth trying

Comment: I tried your method but I am still getting the same error message. I am not sure if it will be part of the markup. I am continuing someone else's work and so not 100% what might be causing it.

Comment: If you're using a modern version of jQuery (1.8+), you can use `$.parseHTML()` to parse the returned HTML instead of plain `$()`. It will not attempt to interpret your input as a selector.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the line feeds

```
$(html.replace(/\n/g,""))...
```

Comment: Line feeds are not enough: if `html` starts with space, it will _not_ be treated as HTML (http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery2).

Comment: With the given fiddle, it would work. If there is a change there is whitespace, the OP would have to use `$.trim()` along with the replace. `$($.trim(html.replace(/\n/g,"")))...`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys for the replies. It was an issue with white spaces as suggested. I ended up removing excess indenting and it fixed it self. I didnt end up having to parse the HTML.

Thanks again. !